# add popup to azure map layer with ng-azure-maps

Tags: azure-maps

I am using [this wrapper](https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/ng-azure-maps) for the azure maps library. I am currently implementing a [popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.popup?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest). When following the [provided example](https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/ng-azure-maps/wiki/Popups), applied to my needs, I cannot get the code to work.

this is my component:

```js
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control';
import {ILayerEvent} from 'ng-azure-maps';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent {
  @Input() locations;

  private markerImagePath = 'assets/images/map-marker.png';

  public dataSource: atlas.source.DataSource;

  public popupContent: string;
  public popupPosition: atlas.data.Position;
  public popupOpened = false;

  public dwOptions: atlas.IconOptions = {
    image: 'marker'
  };

  points = [
    [52.52437, 13.41053],
    [51.50853, -0.12574]
  ];

  mapReady(map: atlas.Map) {
    map.imageSprite.add('marker', this.markerImagePath).then(r => {
      this.dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource('markers');
      this.points.forEach(p => {
        const point = new atlas.Shape(new atlas.data.Point([p[1], p[0]]));
        this.dataSource.add([point]);
      });
    });
  }

  onMouseEnter(e: ILayerEvent): void {
    const point = e.event.shapes['0'].data.geometry.coordinates as [number, number];
    this.showInfo(point);
  }

  onMouseLeave() {
    this.closePopup();
  }

  showInfo(targetPoint: [number, number]): void {
    this.popupPosition = new atlas.data.Position(targetPoint[0], targetPoint[1]);
    this.popupOpened = true;
    this.popupContent = 'Shows on mouse over';
  }

  closePopup(): void { this.popupOpened = false; }
}
```

this is my template:

```html
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 map-dimensions my-2 mx-auto" azure-map zoom="2"
         [dataSources]="[dataSource]" (onReady)="mapReady($event.map)">
      <map-symbol-layer dataSourceId="markers"
                      [iconOptions]="dwOptions"
                      (onMouseEnter)="onMouseEnter($event)"
                      (onMouseLeave)="onMouseLeave()"></map-symbol-layer>
      <map-popup [content]="popupContent"
                 [position]="popupPosition"
                 [opened]="popupOpened"></map-popup>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I really cannot pin down the problem, since the variables are all set and also changed `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`

Comment: Are you seeing the popup up appear but not change as you move between points?

Comment: yes it actually gets opened but at the wrong position (outside of the map) and when I leave the marker position it also doesn't close. It's really weird

Comment: I tried exactly your code with a custom icon and with a `pixelOffset` to make it easier to see the popup, and it gets opened at the correct location. Looks good to me.  Any css which you apply on the popup itself which could be the cause ? Any specific browser you are using ?

Comment: I am using google chrome. I am going to look into the stylesheets and trying to use a `pixelOffset` as well

Comment: For christ sake, I was just missing some js libraries. Thank you for your help though guys!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was missing ?

Comment: This link was missing: https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/service/2/atlas-service.min.js

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to mouse events on layers its good to understand at the layer level, not the feature level. This means that `mouseenter` event will only fire when the mouse initially moves over a feature in the layer and will not fire again until the mouse has left the layer and reentered. If the mouse moves from one feature to another within a layer without leaving the layer, the `mouseenter` event will not fire a second time. The `mouseleave` event works in a similar way. If you want a mouse event that fires as you move the mouse from feature to feature, use the `mousemove` event instead of the `mouseenter` event. For your scenario I would still use the `mouseleave` event.